# Retention of drop down values post submission of form

Tags: php

Following is my code and the structure. The issue is when the form is submitted I can not retain the values of the drop down boxes. can some one please highlight where have I gone wrong? Alternatively if there is a better way to handle this, please do suggest. Thank you.

Note: I have tries to apply above to only one drop down in the following code, But I will be extending the same to both the drop downs.

**Code :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" id="form1">
        <div>
            <div="pickYear">
            <select name="yearPickNow">
            <option value='selectyear'<?php echo isset($_GET["yearPickNow"]) && $_GET["yearPickNow"] == "selectyear" ? "selected" : "" ?>>Year</option>
            <option value="2014" <?php if($_POST['yearPickNow'] == '2014') {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >2014</option>
            <option value='2015'<?php echo isset($_GET["yearPickNow"]) && $_GET["yearPickNow"] == "2015" ? "selected" : "2015" ?>>2015</option>
            <option value='2016'<?php echo isset($_GET["yearPickNow"]) && $_GET["yearPickNow"] == "2016" ? "selected" : "2016" ?>>2016</option>
            <option value='2017'<?php echo isset($_GET["yearPickNow"]) && $_GET["yearPickNow"] == "2017" ? "selected" : "2017" ?>>2017</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div id="pickMonth">
            <select name="monthPickNow" id="monthPickNow" onChange="document.forms['form1'].submit()">
            <option value='selectmonth'>Month</option>
            <option value='January'>January</option>
            <option value='February'>February</option>
            <option value='March'>March</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
        //some php code to bring up and display content relevant to the selected year and month from a SQL database
        ?>
        </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Without delving deeper (there may be more issues) the form method is POST, so the form data will be in `$_POST`, not `$_GET`

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox thanks. yup u were correct!